# how to graph levels in x and y coordinates (level plot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, lattice, levelplot

I have an extensive set of levels of my interest variable (over a year of collection). I would like to plot these levels (there are 3 levels) in coordinates X (date of the year- the day of the year) and Y (time of day- hour).
I am encountering difficulties due to the collection period and also to put a legend with each level.

I would be grateful if anyone could indicate how to compose this graph

My matrix data:
Hour;28/jun;29/jun;30/jun;01/jul;02/jul;03/jul;04/jul;05/jul;06/jul;07/jul;08/jul;09/jul;10/jul;11/jul;12/jul;13/jul;14/jul;15/jul;16/jul;17/jul;18/jul;19/jul;20/jul;21/jul;22/jul;23/jul;24/jul;25/jul;26/jul;27/jul;28/jul;29/jul;30/jul;31/jul;01/ago;02/ago;03/ago;04/ago;05/ago;06/ago;07/ago;08/ago;09/ago;10/ago;11/ago;12/ago;13/ago;14/ago;15/ago;16/ago;17/ago;18/ago;19/ago;20/ago;21/ago;22/ago;23/ago;24/ago;25/ago;26/ago;27/ago;28/ago;29/ago;30/ago;31/ago;01/set;02/set;03/set;04/set;05/set;06/set;07/set;08/set;09/set;10/set;11/set;12/set;13/set;14/set;15/set;16/set;17/set;18/set;19/set;20/set;21/set;22/set;23/set;24/set;25/set;26/set;27/set;28/set;29/set;30/set;01/out;02/out;03/out;04/out;05/out;06/out;07/out;08/out;09/out;10/out;11/out;12/out;13/out;14/out;15/out;16/out;17/out;18/out;19/out;20/out;21/out;22/out;23/out;24/out;25/out;26/out;27/out;28/out;29/out;30/out;31/out;01/nov;02/nov;03/nov;04/nov;05/nov;06/nov;07/nov;08/nov;09/nov;10/nov;11/nov;12/nov;13/nov;14/nov;15/nov;16/nov;17/nov;18/nov;19/nov;20/nov;21/nov;22/nov;23/nov;24/nov;25/nov;26/nov;27/nov;28/nov;29/nov;30/nov;01/dez;02/dez;03/dez;04/dez;05/dez;06/dez;07/dez;08/dez;09/dez;10/dez;11/dez;12/dez;13/dez;14/dez;15/dez;16/dez;17/dez;18/dez;19/dez;20/dez;21/dez;22/dez;23/dez;24/dez;25/dez;26/dez;27/dez;28/dez;29/dez;30/dez;31/dez
0;NA;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;5;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;5;3;3;3;5;3;0;0;0;5;5;5;5;3;3;3;3;3;5;5;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3
0.5;NA;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;5;5;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;5;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;0;5;5;5;5;3;3;3;3;3;5;5;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3
1;NA;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;5;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;5;0;0;0;3;3;0;3;0;5;3;3;0;0;0;5;5;5;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;5;3;3;3;3;5;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3
1.5;NA;3;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;5;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;5;3;0;0;0;0;0;5;5;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;5;3;3;3;3;5;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3
2;NA;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;5;5;5;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;5;5;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;0;5;5;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;0;5;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3
2.5;NA;0;0;5;0;3;3;0;0;5;0;0;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;5;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;3;0;5;3;0;0;0;0;5;5;5;0;0;0;3;0;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;5;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3
3;NA;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;5;5;5;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;5;3;0;0;0;0;5;5;5;0;0;0;3;3;3;5;0;3;3;0;5;0;0;0;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3
3.5;NA;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;5;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;5;0;0;0;0;0;5;5;3;5;3;0;0;0;0;5;5;5;0;0;0;3;0;3;5;0;3;3;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3
4;NA;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;3;0;0;5;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;5;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;5;3;0;0;0;0;5;5;5;3;0;0;3;0;3;0;5;3;3;3;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;0;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3
4.5;NA;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;5;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;3;5;3;0;0;0;0;5;5;3;3;3;0;3;0;5;0;5;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;0;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3
5;NA;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;5;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;3;0;0;0;0;5;5;3;5;0;0;3;0;5;0;0;3;3;3;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3
5.5;NA;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;5;5;0;0;0;0;5;5;5;5;0;0;3;0;5;5;0;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;5;3;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0
6;NA;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;0;5;5;5;5;0;0;3;0;5;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
6.5;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;5;3;0;0;0;0;5;5;5;0;0;0;0;0;5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
7;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
7.5;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
8;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
8.5;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
9;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
9.5;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
10;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
10.5;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
11;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
11.5;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
12;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
12.5;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
13;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
13.5;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
14;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
14.5;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
15;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
15.5;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
16;NA;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
16.5;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
17;3;0;3;0;3;0;3;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;3;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
17.5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
18;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
18.5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;0;0;3
19;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3
19.5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;5;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3
20;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3
20.5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;5;5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3
21;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;5;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;5;5;5;3;3;3;3;3;3;5;5;3;3;3;3;5;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3
21.5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;5;3;0;0;3;5;5;5;3;3;3;3;3;3;5;5;3;3;3;3;5;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3
22;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;5;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;5;3;0;0;5;5;5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;5;5;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3
22.5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;5;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;0;3;3;5;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;5;5;5;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;5;3;3;3;3;3;5;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;5;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3
23;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;5;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;5;5;5;3;5;3;3;3;3;3;5;5;3;3;3;3;5;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3
23.5;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;0;3;0;0;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;0;3;5;5;0;3;3;5;3;0;0;3;5;5;3;5;3;3;3;3;3;0;5;3;3;3;3;5;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;0;3;3;3;0;0;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;0;0;3;0;3;3;3;3

I tried it: http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/27-levelplot-with-lattice/

```
dados=as.matrix(read.table("1_3.txt", header=T, sep = ";"))
head(dados,5)
heatmap(dados, Colv = NA, Rowv = (NA), scale="none", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Hour")
```

But the information on the x- and y-axis becomes unclear and no caption appears

And...https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/133-demineur-dataart/

```
dados <- read.table("1_3.txt", header=T, sep = ";")
y <- dados$Hour
x <- dados[,-1]
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))

data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)
plot(data[,1],data[,2],xaxt="n",yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", bty="n", mar=c(0,0,0,0), pch=20,cex=3,col=rgb(0.2,0.2,0.4,sample(seq(0.2,1,0.001), 10000,replace=T)))
```

But "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments

Comment: As another user has mentioned please use `dput(your_data)` in the future and you'll get more responses. From reading your question I would recommend you look up `stat_density_2d()` which is great at producing heat maps.

Answer (score 1):

It was not very easy for me to copy your data to play around with, but I managed. Please consider using the output of `dput(your_data)` in future questions.

Since somebody tagged this question with ggplot2, I'm going to assume you want to achieve this heatmap of your matrix in ggplot. Assuming `dados` is your matrix, we'll first melt it from a wide format to a long format:

```
df <- reshape2::melt(dados, id.vars = "Hour")
```

Then the next thing to do would be to use ggplot with a raster geom:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = Hour, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster()
```

Which gave me the following plot:

[image]

As is clear to see, the x-axis is quite overcrowded. To fix this, we need to get your annotation of the date into a format that R understands. I'm not really good with dates in R, but you might try something like the following:

```
months <- substr(as.character(df$variable), 4, nchar(as.character(df$variable)))
months <- factor(months, levels = unique(months))
levels(months) <- 6:12
months <- as.numeric(as.character(months))
days <- substr(as.character(df$variable), 1, 2)

df$date <- as.Date(paste0(months, "-", days), format = "%m-%d")
```

And now you can plot with the date as the x axis:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = Hour, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster()
```

[image]

And that should be a decent heatmap to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your tips.
I am a beginner in R and I do not speak English very well, so it is very important to receive these suggestions.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The code to generate the second chart is not working.

The following error appears:
Error in seq.int (0, to0 - from, by): 'to' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min (x): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max (x): in non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min (diff (sort (x))): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Could you help again?

Comment: After what function does that error appear? Can you give me a `head()` of what you are supplying to that function?

Comment: After this code:   `ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = Hour, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster()`
The error message:
`Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number`
 `In addition: Warning messages:`
 `1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`
`2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`
`3: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`

Comment: I do not know if my interpretation is correct but apparently the X-axis information has not been filled, with theses comands: 
`months <- substr(as.character(df$variable), 4,`      
 `nchar(as.character(df$variable)))`     
`months <- factor(months, levels = unique(months))`     
`levels(months) <- 6:12`     
`months <- as.numeric(as.character(months))`     
`days <- substr(as.character(df$variable), 1, 2)`     

`df$date <- as.Date(paste0(months, "-", days), format = "%m-%d")`

Comment: Does you dataset maybe contain more months/dates than the one you posted? Because then you would have to adjust this piece of code: `levels(months) <- 6:12` to reflect the number of months you have. Any way of formatting the `df$variable` to a proper date format would do the trick, there are other ways besides my possibly inefficient code.

Comment: My dataset starts on June 28th and ends on December 31st.
Considering the month of June (although 3 days, only) I have 7 months.
When I change the code to: 
`levels(months) <- 5:12` I still do not have the efficiency in the code

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know where exactly the code breaks down. Have a look at `?as.Date()`, try to figure out a way to get your months in numerical format and days from the column names and format it to a date. You could have a look at the lubridate package.

Answer (score 0):

It worked very well: I just renamed my columns of dates in the original data. I put the name of each month in the first hour of the first day. The rest I left out.
    df <- reshape2::melt(dados, id.vars = "Hour")

```
f1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = Hour, fill = value)) +
geom_raster()+
theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size=12))
f1

f1 + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("Jul","Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))
```

[image]